# Log connection tryings of a software

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I want to know it's posible watch if a software is trying get a connection over internet. I have an strange binary file i want to know if the software  want connect to internet when is execute.

Comment: sure, run `tcpdump`, it will log details of all packets.

Answer (score 1):

Run this program with a separated user, and log all traffic with iptables:

```
iptables -A OUTPUT -m owner --uid-owner otheruser -j LOG
```

Then you will find the log in dmesg. Watch via `dmesg -w` or `tail -f /var/log/kern.log`.

Answer (score 0):

You can monitor the applications with connections over the internet with application `nethogs`. This is like `Resource Monitor` in Windows (the network pane).

You can use it to see the application using the internet and the bandwidth used for every application.